# React Native Vision Camera -> MaxImage Buffer Problem

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

Currently I am having a weird problem . I am using this package `react-native-vision-camera`(3.9.0) and `react-native`(0.71.14) . So when i tried to scan a QR on my project it has this error

> W/ImageReader_JNI: Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers

But when I tried it on a fresh project it does work and can scan a QR without that error above .

So I am asking what could be the possible reason or configuration needed or file to check to why is this happening.

a bit of information :

gradle.properties :

> VisionCamera_disableFrameProcessors=true

build.gradle :

> implementation("com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0")

and for the code is just like this

```
<Camera
   style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
   device={device}
   isActive={scannerActive}
   codeScanner={detectedBarcode}
   {...(Platform.OS === 'ios' && {frameProcessor})}
/>
```

Hoping someone could enlighten me . Thank you.

Edited :

> E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"

> E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

it seems like I have also this error on my logcat which is I miss out.

Comment: I'm using react-native-qrcode-scanner for my both Android n IOS and it's working.. but need some tweak.. maybe you can try it..

Comment: This repo is suggesting to migrate to `react-native-vision-camera` .